# Symfony2 functional testing of Access Denied

Tags: php, symfony, functional-testing

I want to build a functional test in Symfony2 to check that guests are redirected to login, some user types are allowed on page and other are shown Access Denied.

First two I did with zero problems but whenever I try to access that page in Access Denied scenario my terminal gets flooded with content of that page (which is whole bunch of traces and debugs).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate environment for running tests, and setup debugging to false.

I am not sure how you are running your tests, but if they are going through the front controller (app_dev.php), do the following:

Copy app_dev.php to app_test.php

Change

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

to

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('test', false);
```

The second parameter is a $debug flag.

You can also comment out:

```
//Debug::enable();
```

**EDIT:**

From the documentation, to override the debug parameter for functional tests you have to use:

```
$client = static::createClient(array(
    'environment' => 'my_test_env',
    'debug'       => false,
));
```

Comment: Nope, didn't help :(

Errors are still flooding my terminal :(

Comment: Have you tried catching a AccessDeniedException in your test?

The full namespace is Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException , for phpunit reference see http://phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.exceptions.examples.ExceptionTest.php

Comment: Also check http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#testing-configuration on how to override the default debug mode for testing.

Comment: It worked with setting up createClient. That is only change needed.
                 'environment' => 'test',
                 'debug'       => false,
            )
        );